# Openpyxl : need the max number of rows in a column that has data in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need the last row in a particular column that contains data in Excel. In openpyxl sheet.max_row or max_column gets us the maximum row or column in the whole sheet. But what I want is for a particular column.

My scenario is where I have to get some values from database and append it to the end of a particular column in Excel sheet.

In this screenshot, if I want max_column containing data in column 'C', it should return 10:

[image]

In the above image if I want last cell containing data  of column 'C', it should return 10

------------- Solution 1 --------------------

```
import pandas as pd

# lt is the dataframe containing the data to be loaded to excel file

for index,i in enumerate(lt):
   panda_xl_rd = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',"sheet_Name") # Panda Dataframe
   max = len(panda_xl_rd.iloc[:,(col-1)].dropna())+2     ''' getting the 
                                                             row_num of 
                                                             last record in 
                                                             column 
                                                             dropna removes 
                                                             the Nan 
                                                             values else we 
                                                             will get 
                                                             the entire 
                                                             sheets max 
                                                             column length . 
                                                             +2 gets 
                                                             the next column 
                                                             right after the 
                                                             last column to 
                                                             enter data '''
   cellref = sheet.cell(row = max+index, column=col)
   cellref.value = i
   del panda_xl_rd
```

------------------------Solution 2 ----------------------

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816289/10003981

------------------------Solution 3 ----------------------

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817637/10003981

Maybe solution 3 is a more concise one !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**:  i want max_column containing data in Column 'C' it should return 10:

Simple count `cell.value not Empty`
Documentation [Accessing many cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file)

> **PSEUDOCODE**
>
> ```
> for cell in Column('C'):
>     if not cell.value is empty:
>         count += 1
> ```

---

> **Comment**: What if we have an empty cell in between?

Count the Rows in sync with the Column Range, and use a `maxRowWithData` variable. This will also work with **no** empty cell between.

> **PSEUDOCODE**
>
> ```
> for row index, cell in enumerate Column('C'):
>     if not cell.value is empty:
>         maxRowWithData = row index
> ```
>
> **Note**: The cell index of `openpyxl` is **1-based**!

Documentation:  [enumerate(iterable, start=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: What if we have an empty cell in between? Normally we would'nt have , but just being curious

Comment: This is working good for me !! Thanks for the prompt reply . Will update both solutions in the question section itself!!

Comment: it is throwing error : NameError: name 'empty' is not defined

Comment: @ChandraShekhar ***"NameError: name 'empty' is not defined"***: Have you noticed the word **PSEUDOCODE**, means it is not working code. You have to extend it to valid Python code for your needs.

Comment: @stovfl Thanks I had missed that word

Answer (score 3):

"Empty" is a relative concept so your code should be clear about this. The methods in openpyxl are guaranteed to return orthogonal result sets: the length of rows and columns will always be the same.

Using this we can work deduce the row highest row in column of a cell where the value is not None.

```
max_row_for_c = max((c.row for c in ws['C'] if c.value is not None))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply ! But this is just returning me the Column name : 'C'

Answer (score 1):

why not just find the length of column 'C'
result would be same output-->10
because when u will get the column 'C' values it will present u as tuple elements
so just take length of tuple which would come =10

```
import Openpyxl

file=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

current_sheet=file.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')  

Column_C=current_sheet['C']   

print ( len(column_C))

data.close()
data.closed()
```

Comment: Please separate your explanations from code and provide a full code block formatted correctly with a working solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct if an empty cell in between two cells with values then it will fail the following is the correct way.

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    Dir_Name = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Your_Project_Folder_Name_Here')
    xl_file_path = os.path.join(Dir_Name, 'Your_Excel_File_Name_Here.xlsx')
    wb_obj = xl.load_workbook(xl_file_path)
    sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
    number_of_rows = sheet_obj.max_row
    last_row_index_with_data = 0
    while True:
        if sheet_obj.cell(number_of_rows, 1).value != None:
            last_row_index_with_data = number_of_rows
            break
        else:
            number_of_rows -= 1

    print( "last row index having values " , last_row_index_with_data)
```

In this way we check from bottom to top of the page, when we find a cell that has a value other than a None, that index of row is the one we are requiring.

Answer (score -1):

I think I just found a way using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# lt is the dataframe containing the data to be loaded to excel file

for index,i in enumerate(lt):
    panda_xl_rd = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',"sheet_Name") # Panda Dataframe
    max = len(panda_xl_rd.iloc[:,(col-1)].dropna())+2     ''' getting the row_num of 
                                                            last record in column 
                                                            dropna removes the Nan 
                                                            values else we will get 
                                                            the entire sheets max 
                                                            column length . +2 gets 
                                                            the next column right 
                                                            after the last column to 
                                                            enter data '''
    cellref = sheet.cell(row = max+index, column=col)
    cellref.value = i
    del panda_xl_rd
```