# Length of Specific Excel Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have my workbook and worksheet defined and have openpyxl / pandas imported.

Anyway I have data in multiple excel columns. Data in columns A and B are larger datasets. I'm trying to count the length of column C in order to paste a dataframe starting at the last row with values in column C.

Using the function len(ws['C']) returns the max row of the sheet. (replacing C with any other column, returns the same value)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Relevant [need the max number of rows in a column that has data in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816289/7414759)

Comment: You should always include what code you've tried so far.